# Interchange Summation Indexes - Möbius Inversion Formula

Tags: number-theory, summation, arithmetic-functions

I'm reading a book that prove the first part of Möbius Inversion Formula exactly like this:

($\Rightarrow$)
Suppose that

$$f(n)=\sum_{d|n}g(d).$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)f\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)&=\sum_{dd'=n}\mu(d)f\left(d'\right)\\
&=\sum_{dd'=n}\mu(d)\sum_{m|d'}g(m)\\
&=\sum_{dmh=n}\mu(d)g(m)\tag{1.1}\\
&=\sum_{mh'=n}g(m)\sum_{d|h'}\mu(d).\tag{1.2}\end{align}$$

But $\sum_{d|h'}\mu(d)=0$ for $h'>1$. Hence $$\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)f\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)=g(n).$$

I understood everything except why we can go from 1.1 to 1.2. I found similar questions on the internet, but I couldn't understand the answers either.

I'm realizing that this is not the first time that I have not understood how to interchange summation indexes.  It might be interesting for me to do a more careful study of summations, so in addition to the proof explanation, I'm looking for books and videos that better explain how summation works and, in particular, how index interchange works.

Feel free to point out mistakes in my writing as well (I'm not used to writing in English).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to begin by remarking that your English appears immaculate! I would not have guessed that you're not used to writing in English if you had not said it...

The general idea with sum index-interchanges is just some careful thought about precisely what terms a sum iterates over and why are the same in the new index-order.

If a term is summed in (1.1), then it is $\mu(d)g(m)$ for some triple $(d,m,h)\in\mathbb{N}^3$ such that $dmh = n$. If we were to group $dmh = m(dh) = mh'$ then notice $d|h'$. Therefore, we get a triple $(m,h',d)\in\mathbb{N}^3$ such that $mh' = n$ and $d|h'$ and thus this term appears in the sum (1.2).

Similarly, suppose a term is summed in (1.2) then it's $g(m)\mu(d)$ for some triple $(m,h',d)\in\mathbb{N}^3$ such that $mh' = n$ and $d|h'$. But then from this triple we can form the new triple $(d,m,h'/d)\in\mathbb{N}^3$ such that $d\cdot m\cdot (h'/d) = n$. Thus this term appears in the sum (1.1).

That's all there really is to sum index-interchange: there are finitely many terms in both cases and we sum over the same set in both cases but the underlying set is represented differently in some way. We just need to see that the set is the same in both sums; in the above I showed that by showing that the set of summed terms in (1.1) and (1.2) are subsets of each other and so the same. After a while, you'll get used to this and you won't need to write out something like the above and instead just "see" it but for now perhaps try to write out the argument when you find a tricky index change.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I understood. I usually need some time to fully understand something. In that case maybe I still have to test numerically to prove to myself that it works.

Answer (score 1):

We look at this formula somewhat more detailed with focus on symmetry. At first we consider the *[Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution)*
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\left(\mu\ast f\right)(n)}&:=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)f\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)
=\sum_{dd^{\prime}=n}\mu(d)f\left(d^{\prime}\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{dd^{\prime}=n}\mu\left(d^{\prime}\right)f(d)=\sum_{d|n}f(d)\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(f\ast\mu\right)(n)}
\end{align*}

Note that (1) is also the start of OPs formula. By using symmetries we see the Dirichlet convolution is *commutative*.

We introduce the *constant function* $u$ with $u(n)=1, n\in\mathbb{N}$, which enables us to put the focus somewhat more on symmetries. We can write this way OPs relation between $f$ and $g$ as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f(n)}&=\sum_{d|n}g(d)=\sum_{d|n}g(d)\cdot 1\\
&=\sum_{d|n}g(d)u\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)=\sum_{dd^{\prime}=n}g(d)u\left(d^\prime\right)\tag{2}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(g\ast u\right)(n)}
\end{align*}

Note that (1) and (2) show the same form.

> We obtain from (1) and (2)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(\mu\ast f\right)(n)}&:=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)f\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)
> =\sum_{dd^{\prime}=n}\mu(d)f\left(d^{\prime}\right)\tag{3.1}\\
> &=\sum_{dd^{\prime}=n}\mu(d)\sum_{m|d^{\prime}}g(m)u\left(\frac{d^{\prime}}{m}\right)\tag{3.2}\\
> &=\sum_{dd^{\prime}=n}\mu(d)\sum_{mm^{\prime}=d^{\prime}}g(m)u\left(m^{\prime}\right)\tag{3.3}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\sum_{dmm^{\prime}=n}\mu(d)g(m)u\left(m^{\prime}\right)}\tag{3.4}\\
> &=\sum_{md^{\prime}=n}g(m)\sum_{dm^{\prime}=d^{\prime}}\mu(d)u\left(m^{\prime}\right)\tag{3.5}\\
> &=\sum_{md^{\prime}=n}g(m)\sum_{d|d^{\prime}}\mu(d)u\left(\frac{d^{\prime}}{d}\right)\tag{3.6}\\
> &=\sum_{m|n}g(m)\sum_{d|d^{\prime}}\mu(d)\tag{3.7}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=g(n)}
> \end{align*}

*Comments:*

- In (3.1) we use the representation from (1).
- In (3.2) we use the representation from (2).
- Note the symmetry between (3.3) with (3.5) and the symmetry between (3.2) and (3.6) which nicely show the relationship between these transformations.
- In (3.7) we use that $u$ is the constant function $u= 1$ and obtain the representation as in OPs derivation.

**Notes:**

- The arithmetic *unit* function $I(n):=\begin{cases}1&\quad n=1\\0&\quad \text{else}\end{cases}\qquad$ fulfills
  \begin{align*}
   f\ast I=f=I\ast f
   \end{align*}
- We also have the relationship $\mu\ast u=I=u\ast \mu$.
- OPs derivation above can be written using the associativity of the Dirichlet convolution as
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\mu\ast f}&=\mu\ast\left(g\ast u\right)
  =\mu\ast\left(u\ast g\right)
  =\left(\mu\ast u\right)\ast g
  =I\ast g
  \color{blue}{=g}
  \end{align*}

This derivation and many more relations of *[arithmetic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function)* are nicely and thoroughly explained in the classic *[Introduction to Analytic Number Theory](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/introduction-to-analytic-number-theory-0)* by T. M. Apostol.

Answer (score 1):

The step from (1.1) to (1.2) can be split into three smaller steps,
each similar to one of three steps into which the step before (1.1) can be split:

\begin{align*}
& \phantom{{}={}} \sum_{dd'=n}\mu(d)\sum_{m|d'}g(m) \\
& = \sum_{dd'=n}\mu(d)\sum_{mh=d'}g(m) \\
& = \sum_{dd'=n}\;\sum_{mh=d'}\mu(d)g(m) \\
& = \sum_{dmh=n}\mu(d)g(m) \tag{1.1} \\
& = \sum_{mh'=n}\;\sum_{dh=h'}\mu(d)g(m) \\
& = \sum_{mh'=n}g(m)\sum_{dh=h'}\mu(d) \\
& = \sum_{mh'=n}g(m)\sum_{d|h'}\mu(d) \tag{1.2}
\end{align*}

If the step before (1.1) was already clear, then the step from (1.1)
to (1.2) should now also be clear.

That does not mean that even the smaller steps are trivial, however!
You may still have questions about the validity of such arguments in
general.  If so, then you are right to do so, because it is not at
all easy to find references on the subject, and proofs of general
results of this type ought to be seen by everybody at least once in
their lives (even if only then to be quickly forgotten).

Each of the smaller steps can be justified by a general rule for
calculating with finite sums. (If I haven't slipped up, that is.  My
concentration is not great at the moment, so please do point out any
steps that remain obscure, and I'll try to fix them.)  Most of these
general rules are spelled out by Terence Tao in *Analysis I* (2006), section 7.1.

There is sometimes a need for a more general version of Tao's rule
7.1.11(e).  The only references I have for such a general rule (one
is by Bourbaki, the other was written by me as an answer in Maths.SE
last year) are both pretty hard to read.  Fortunately, all that is
needed in many cases is Tao's slightly less general Lemma 7.1.13, or
Corollary 7.1.14: "Fubini's theorem for finite series".
Less fortunately, it is the more general rule that is needed twice in the
above derivation, to justify the steps immediately before and after (1.1).

I won't state such a rule in full generality, because I went over
the top doing so in an answer to my
[question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612664) on the
subject last year (and even that could be generalised a bit more).
A slimmed-down version of the rule will do.  Let $K$ be a finite
set, $(A_k)_{k \in K}$ a pairwise disjoint family of finite sets,
$B = \bigcup_{k \in K}A_k,$ and $u \colon B \to \mathbb{C}$ a
function. Then
$$
\sum_{b \in B}u(b) = \sum_{k \in K}\sum_{a \in A_k}u(a).
$$

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and define:
\begin{align*}
K & = \{m \in \mathbb{N} : m \mid n\}, \\
A_m & = \{(m, d, h) \in \mathbb{N}^3 : mdh = n\} && (m \in K), \\
B & = \{(m, d, h) \in \mathbb{N}^3 : mdh = n\}, \\
u(m, d, h) & = \mu(d)g(m) && ((m, d, h) \in B).
\end{align*}
Then the rule just given (in conjunction with some simpler rules
that I haven't stated, but that are stated in Tao's book) justifies
the step immediately after (1.1).

If I can find time (it's not likely to happen today), I'll try to
expand this answer by quoting all of the other rules that have
implicitly been appealed to in the above derivation, and showing how
they can be applied explicitly. (That is, unless someone begs me to
stop!) :)

---

Three rules have been applied.  They are:

($\alpha$)
Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets, $\theta \colon A \to B$ a bijection,
and $u \colon B \to \mathbb{C}$ a function. Then
$$
\sum_{a \in A}u(\theta(a)) = \sum_{b \in B}u(b).
$$

($\beta$)
Let $A$ be a finite set, $u \colon A \to \mathbb{C}$ a function, and
$c$ a complex number.  Then
$$
\sum_{a \in A}cu(a) = c\sum_{a \in A}u(a).
$$

($\gamma$)
Let $K$ be a finite set, $(A_k)_{k \in K}$ a pairwise disjoint
family of finite sets, $B = \bigcup_{k \in K}A_k,$ and
$u \colon B \to \mathbb{C}$ a function. Then
$$
\sum_{b \in B}u(b) = \sum_{k \in K}\sum_{a \in A_k}u(a).
$$

The derivation has six steps.

The first step uses rule ($\alpha$), with
\begin{align*}
A & = \{(m, h) \in \mathbb{N}^2 : mh = d'\}, \\
B & = \{m \in \mathbb{N} : m \mid d'\}, \\
\theta(m, h) & = m && ((m, h) \in A), \\
u(m) & = g(m) && (m \in B).
\end{align*}

The second step uses rule ($\beta$), with
\begin{align*}
A & = \{(m, h) \in \mathbb{N}^2 : mh = d'\}, \\
u(m, h) & = g(m) && ((m, h) \in A), \\
c & = \mu(d).
\end{align*}

The third step uses rule ($\gamma$), with
\begin{align*}
K & = \{d \in \mathbb{N} : d \mid n\}, \\
A_d & = \{(m, d, h) \in \mathbb{N}^3 : mdh = n\} && (d \in K), \\
B & = \{(m, d, h) \in \mathbb{N}^3 : mdh = n\}, \\
u(m, d, h) & = \mu(d)g(m) && ((m, d, h) \in B).
\end{align*}

At the same time, the third step uses rule ($\alpha$), with
\begin{align*}
A & = \{(m, h) \in \mathbb{N}^2 : mh \mid n\}, \\
B & = \{(m, d, h) \in \mathbb{N}^3 : mdh = n\}, \\
\theta(m, h) & = (m, n/(mh), h) && ((m, h) \in A), \\
u(m, d, h) & = \mu(d)g(m) && ((m, d, h) \in B).
\end{align*}

If this is confusing, it is because the notation in use, although it
is compact, convenient, and perfectly standard, does not permit the
application of rule ($\alpha$) to be represented
explicitly in this instance. (But I'll think some more about this,
and edit the answer again, if I or someone else can come up with a
clearer way to represent this step of the derivation.  The important
thing is to represent it in terms of general rules in *some*
way; but this may not be the best way.)

The fourth step also uses rule ($\gamma$), as was
explained in the part of the answer written yesterday.

At the same time, it uses rule ($\alpha$), with
\begin{align*}
A & = \{(d, h) \in \mathbb{N}^2 : dh \mid n\}, \\
B & = \{(m, d, h) \in \mathbb{N}^3 : mdh = n\}, \\
\theta(d, h) & = (n/(dh), d, h) && ((d, h) \in A), \\
u(m, d, h) & = \mu(d)g(m) && ((m, d, h) \in B).
\end{align*}

The fifth step uses rule ($\beta$), with
\begin{align*}
A & = \{(d, h) \in \mathbb{N}^2 : dh = h'\}, \\
u(d, h) & = \mu(d) && ((d, h) \in A), \\
c & = g(m).
\end{align*}

The sixth and final step uses rule ($\alpha$), with
\begin{align*}
A & = \{(d, h) \in \mathbb{N}^2 : dh = h'\}, \\
B & = \{d \in \mathbb{N} : d \mid h'\}, \\
\theta(d, h) & = d && ((d, h) \in A), \\
u(d) & = \mu(d) && (d \in B).
\end{align*}

Of course, one can work through such derivations intuitively and
confidently without splitting them up into tiny steps like this!
But it helps to demystify the logic of such arguments if one knows
they can be reduced to applications of a few simple and general
rules, whose truth is entirely obvious. (Their proofs need not be
remembered, although they should be seen at least once.) And where
difficulties arise, I think it can be of practical help to make some
of the applications of the rules explicit, even if not at this
painful level of detail.